# C Pointer Copying

Tags: c, pointers

I am programming a compiler, I have this code:

```
CLOSURE *find_func(TOKEN* name, FRAME* e){
    FRAME *ef = e;
     while(ef != NULL){
        while (ef->bindings != NULL){
            if(ef->bindings->name ==  name){
               return ef->bindings->value->closure;
            }
            ef->bindings = ef->bindings->next;
        }
         ef = ef->next;
     }
     printf("No function %s in scope, exiting...\n",name->lexeme);exit(1);
}
```

My understanding was that when I make a copy of e into ef, and then perform my loop with ef, it would not change the address stored in e? However this code does; when I go ef=ef->next, it also increments e. Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "it also increments e"? How do you determine that that happens?

Comment: Reassigning `ef` doesn't modify `e`. But the assignment `ef->bindings = ef->bindings->next` will modify `e->bindings` if `ef == e`

Comment: `e` and `ef` are not related, but they may reference the same object. Then if you modify the object referenced by `ef` it will be visible when you dereference `e` as they reference the same object.

Comment: @UnholySheep with a debugger of course

Comment: And then there are effects of optimization. Since C only passes arguments by value, `e` holds a **copy** of whatever you pass at the call. The compiler is free to use the same resource (register, stack space) for `e` and `ef`, since `e` is not used after the initial assignment. Look at parameters as local variables.

Comment: Let the debugger tell you at assembly level, where `e` and `ef` are stored.

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense. So, how can I iterate through the bindings/frames without changing the original FRAME e?

Comment: Use a separated variable for the bindings' chain.

Comment: @thebusybee that makes sense, but when I step out to the function that calls find_func(), its copy of e is also modified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239049/discussion-between-the-busybee-and-e-god).

Comment: BTW, there's no need to make a copy of `e`. Assigning it doesn't affect the caller's variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not modifying `e`, but you're modifying the frames that it points to when you assign `ef->bindings`.

So use a new variable for that instead of the structure member.

```
CLOSURE *find_func(TOKEN* name, FRAME* e){
    FRAME *ef = e;
    while(ef != NULL){
        BINDINGS *ef_bindings = ef->bindings;
        while (ef_bindings != NULL){
            if(ef_bindings->name ==  name){
               return ef_bindings->value->closure;
            }
            ef_bindings = ef_bindings->next;
        }
        ef = ef->next;
    }
    printf("No function %s in scope, exiting...\n",name->lexeme);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, credit to @thebusybee for giving this answer too